# How do I make this iterate again work properly

Tags: python, calculator

I wrote this code to make a calculator with python. I wanted it to perform a task and continue doing that task with new inputs until an input is entered to stop. I already got a code from chat GPT but I want to know I f I can do it with this code structure. And for some reason the programme asks for operation twice

I want to build a calculator with python. First it asks for a operation then asks for operand 1 and two then performs the calculation and then redo it until an input is entered to exit. And I want the program to ask for an operation input if the last character of the input is "$" and I want it to terminate the programme if the last character is "#"

```
    # -------------------------------------
# TODO: Write the select_op(choice) function here
# This function should cover Task 1 (Section 2) and Task 3
    #name     #parameter

def select_op():
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
        if choice.endswith("$"):
            select_op()
        elif choice not in ("+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%", "#", "$"):
            print("Unrecognized operation")
            select_op()
        elif choice.endswith("#"):
            exit()

        else:
            return choice
select_op()


#first_operand = (input("Enter first number: "))
#second_operand = (input("Enter second number: "))



def select_operand():
    try:
        first_operand = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
        return first_operand

    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number. Please enter again.")
        return select_operand()
          # Return to prevent further execution




def select_operand_2():
    try:
        second_operand = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
        return second_operand

    except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid number. Please enter again.")
        return select_operand_2()
        # Return to prevent further execution





first_operand = select_operand()
second_operand = select_operand_2()
choice = select_op()




def operation(choice, first_operand, second_operand):
    if choice == "+" :
        print(first_operand +second_operand)

    elif choice == "-" :
        print(first_operand - second_operand)
    elif choice == "*" :
        print(first_operand * second_operand)
    elif choice == "/" :
        print(first_operand/second_operand)
        if second_operand == 0:
            print("Division by zero is not allowed")
        else:
            print(first_operand / second_operand)
    elif choice == "^" :
        print(first_operand ** second_operand)
    elif choice == "%" :
        print(first_operand % second_operand)
operation(choice, first_operand, second_operand)# End the select_op(choice) function here
# -------------------------------------

while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add      : + ")
    print("2.Subtract : - ")
    print("3.Multiply : * ")
    print("4.Divide   : / ")
    print("5.Power    : ^ ")
    print("6.Remainder: % ")
    print("7.Terminate: # ")
    print("8.Reset    : $ ")

    # take input from the user






    choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
    print(choice)
    if choice.endswith("#"):
        # program ends here
        print("Done. Terminating")


    enter code here

        exit()
```

Comment: `I wrote this code`: nice, care to post it in your question?

Comment: Apperently it doesen't let me format I don't know why. I'm literally tying to figur this out

Answer (score 0):

> *"... for some reason the programme asks for operation twice ..."*

This is because you are calling the methods recursively.

For example, from *select_op*,

```py
if choice.endswith("$"):
    select_op()
```

And, *select_operand*,

```py
except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid number. Please enter again.")
    return select_operand()
    # Return to prevent further execution
```

And, *select_operand_2*.

```py
except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid number. Please enter again.")
    return select_operand_2()
    # Return to prevent further execution
```

Then, you call the methods, from the enclosing scope.

```py
select_op()
...
first_operand = select_operand()
second_operand = select_operand_2()
choice = select_op()
...
operation(choice, first_operand, second_operand)
```

> *'... I want to build a calculator with python. First it asks for a operation then asks for operand 1 and two then performs the calculation and then redo it until an input is entered to exit. And I want the program to ask for an operation input if the last character of the input is "$" and I want it to terminate the programme if the last character is "#" ...'*

Here is an example.

```py
stop = False
while not stop:
    a = input('operand 1:  ')
    while not a.isdigit():
        if a == '':
            stop = True
            break
        print('invalid, try again')
        a = input('operand 1:  ')
    if stop: break
    b = input('operand 2:  ')
    while not b.isdigit():
        if b == '':
            stop = True
            break
        print('invalid, try again')
        b = input('operand 2:  ')
    if stop: break
    op = input('operator * / + - ^ %:  ')
    while op not in '*/+-^%':
        if op == '':
            stop = True
            break
        print('invalid, try again')
        op = input('operator * / + - ^ %:  ')
    if stop: break
    print(f'{a} {op} {b} = {eval(a + op + b)}')
```

Output

```
operand 1:  1
operand 2:  2
operator * / + - ^ %:  +
1 + 2 = 3
operand 1:  123
operand 2:  456
operator * / + - ^ %:  *
123 * 456 = 56088
operand 1:
```

And, here is a more *object-oriented* approach.

```py
def operand1():
    a = input('operand 1:  ')
    while not a.isdigit():
        if a == '': break
        error()
        a = input('operand 1:  ')
    return a

def operand2():
    b = input('operand 2:  ')
    while not b.isdigit():
        if b == '': break
        error()
        b = input('operand 2:  ')
    return b

def operator():
    op = input('operator * / + - ^ %:  ')
    while op not in '*/+-^%':
        if op == '': break
        error()
        op = input('operator * / + - ^ %:  ')
    return op

def error(): print('invalid, try again')

stop = False
while not stop:
    a = operand1()
    if a == '': break
    b = operand2()
    if b == '': break
    op = operator()
    if op == '': break
    print(f'{a} {op} {b} = {eval(a + op + b)}')
```